# Someone help my script auto-hotkey with discord?

Tags: autohotkey

I have a script with auto-hotkey which works like like this:

- Every other minute, it will auto-type a message.
- The next minute, it will delete the auto-typed message automatically.

The script I am using was working before but now it isn't and I have no idea why.  The auto-typing messages still works but deleting them (properly) does not.

The problem I am encountering is that when the delete message function gets called, it only removes the last character at the end of the text block.

***Example:***

- If I auto-set the message to
  `"how to save the world"`
- Auto-delete only removes the last char (the "d") so I get
  `"how to save the worl"`

Would someone be able to tell me what I am doing wrong so I can fix this problem myself?
I would be very grateful for the help!

If you are unable to spot the flaw, I myself run directly against discord to test/run my script.  Running against the same environment should reproduce the error.

Here is the script:

```
/*  
 Notes:  
  Set message in line 6.
  Set delay between messages (in milliseconds) in line 7. 
*/  
 
#singleInstance force   
delay = 60500  
msg =  Hi guys. I'm very apologize for the delay. I found a bug issue about Matchmaking and it's not good for u guys to try this. I will fix this out for a few days and after we sure that it's work for many people. We will do the official announcement Our team try to be quick as much as possible for about this problem. I will try to solve this within this week. BUG : 1. Sometime Match Making match to a person that close the app already (that's mean it will match offline person forever) 
 
`::  ; Toggle autoTyper   
  send % !auto ? msg "{enter}" :   
  setTimer, autoTyper, % !auto ? delay : "off"   
  notify("Auto-Typer", (auto:=!auto) ? "ON" : "OFF")   
return   
autoTyper:   
  send %msg%{enter}   
return   
 
notify(alert, status = 0) {   
  global   
  gui +alwaysOnTop +toolWindow -caption +E0x20   
  gui color, black    
  gui font, cWhite s40 bold, arial   
  gui add, text, vNotification center w700   
  alert := alert " " status   
  guiControl,, notification, % alert   
  gui, show, autosize   
  opacity = 0   
  sleep 775  ; Maintain notification   
  gui destroy   
} 
 
z:: 
{ 
send, {Up} 
send, ^a 
send, {BS} 
send, {Enter} 
send, {Enter} 
sleep, 100 
} 
return
```

Comment: Did you try Send ^a and then {Delete} instead of {BS}?

Comment: Yes, that's right